# Finding intermediate exit status of command in series of ||

Tags: bash, scripting, pipe

Given the following compound command:

```
try_this || or_this || fine_this
```

try_this will return 2, or_this will return 3, and fine_this will return 0.

How would one figure out the exit status of or_this after this execution? I'm under the impression it's not possible unless there is something similar to *PIPESTATUS* or *pipefail* for pipes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, but nothing stops you from storing the exit status somewhere on the side yourself. For instance:

```
storing_exit_status() {
  local dest=$1
  shift

  "$@"; local retval=$?

  printf -v "$dest" %d "$retval"
  return "$retval"
}

storing_exit_status try_this_retval try_this \
  || storing_exit_status or_this_retval or_this \
  || fine_this

echo "$try_this_retval"
```